# Change the shape that shows a for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

FSTAB=` grep -vE "^#|swap|UUID" /etc/fstab  | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'`

for i in $FSTAB
do

   echo "$i"

done
```

return this:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root
/
xfs
/dev/sdb2
/hdos
xfs
```

The problem is that later I want to compare it, so I am returning it with line breaks and I want it to be returned in a single line without jumps, that is to say:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root / xfs
/dev/sdb2 /hdos xfs
```

Comment: `for [...]; done | tr -d '\n'`.

Comment: You'd better let us know what you are compare it to later (or even better, what the overall issue is that you're trying to solve). It may not be needed to output anything at all.  In fact, the safest way to store the pathnames for later use would be in an array.  That would enable you to handle pathnames with whitespaces and other funky names.

Comment: Not an answer but your `FSTAB` could be reduced to: `grep -vE "^#|swap|UUID" /etc/fstab | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'`

Comment: Or `awk '$0 ! ~ /^#|swap|UUID/ {print $1, $2, $3}' /etc/fstab`.

Comment: And also the output you are looking for would be achieved from simply removing the loop altogether and echoing the contents of `FSTAB`

Comment: Or letting `awk` write to stdout (:

Comment: My life got a lot easier (and involved a lot fewer pipe fittings) the day I realized that `grep`ping into `awk` is a kissing cousin to the Useless Use of Cat.

Comment: then I want to compare it with the output of this command mount | grep -e "^ /" | awk '{print $ 1, $ 3, $ 5}'

Comment: line by line.........

Comment: `diff < <(awk '$0 ! ~ /^#|swap|UUID/ {print $1,$2,$3}' /etc/fstab) < <(mount | awk '$0 ! ~ /^ /{print $1,$3,$5}')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of how you fill the `FSTAB` variable, the unquoted expansion of it in the `for` loop removes the distinction between different kinds of white space. (See: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters))

To work around that, either set `IFS` to split only on newlines, or loop over the lines with a `while read` loop:

```
$ fstab=$(grep /etc/fstab ...)
$ while IFS= read -r line; do 
    printf "$line\n"
  done <<< "$fstab"
```

You could also use `while read -r dev mnt fs; do ...` if you wanted the fields in separate variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your entire variable assignment command chain there can be done in one `awk` rather than piping `grep`'s output into `awk`:

```
FSTAB=` grep -v "^#" /etc/fstab | grep . | grep -v "swap" | grep -v "UUID"   | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'`
```

can instead be

```
FSTAB="$(awk 'NF && $0 !~ /^#|swap|UUID/ {print $1, $2, $3}' /etc/fstab)"
```

Newlines will be embedded in the variable, so you don't need to loop anything, you can simply `echo "$FSTAB"`.

However, rather than parsing `/etc/fstab` into a variable and then parsing *that*, it would probably be better to parse `/etc/fstab` directly with a more involved `awk` script that does exactly what you need to with the output you're currently scraping from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just *GNU* `egrep`:

```
egrep -v "^#|swap|UUID" /etc/fstab  | egrep -o '^(\S*\s*){1,3}'
```